# Proving that $\alpha:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ where $\alpha(x)=\frac{x^{3}}{x^{2}+1}$ is bijective

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Using the usual method that I was taught, in order to find that something is injective, I assume $f(x)=f(y)$ for some $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, and then I demonstrate that $x=y$. This is not working out so well for me, using the following steps:

\begin{align}
\frac{x^{3}}{x^{2}+1}&=\frac{y^{3}}{y^{2}+1}\\
x^3(y^2+1)&=y^3(x^2+1)\\
x^3y^2+x^3&=x^2y^3+y^3\\
x^3-y^3&=x^2y^3-x^3y^2\\
(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)&=x^2y^2(y-x)\\
(x^2+xy+y^2)&=-x^2y^2\\
x^2+y^2&=-x^2y^2-xy\\
x^2+y^2&=-xy(xy+1)
\end{align}

And here is where I'm stuck. Am I assuming correctly that I should find that $x=y$ somehow?

Comment: Hint:  a good way to show a function is injective is to show it is strictly increasing or decreasing.

Comment: And if you want surjectivity too, examine the limits as $x\to\pm\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $f(x) = f(y)$ and showing that $x = y$ is a correct method to show that $f$ is injective. You have one subtle error in your work.

> $\begin{align} \frac{x^{3}}{x^{2}+1}&=\frac{y^{3}}{y^{2}+1}\\
>  x^3(y^2+1)&=y^3(x^2+1)\\ x^3y^2+x^3&=x^2y^3+y^3\\
>  x^3-y^3&=x^2y^3-x^3y^2\\ (x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)&=x^2y^2(y-x)\\
>  (x^2+xy+y^2)&=-x^2y^2\\ \end{align}$

At the last step shown above, you divided both sides by $x-y$, which could potentially be $0$.

Continuing from above, you get that $f(x) = f(y)$ implies $$(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)=x^2y^2(y-x)$$, which can be rewritten as $$(x-y)(x^2y^2+x^2+xy+y^2) = 0$$

Here, there are two possibilities. Either $x-y = 0$, i.e. $x = y$ (which is what we want to show) or $x^2y^2+x^2+xy+y^2 = 0$. So you need to show that $x^2y^2+x^2+xy+y^2 = 0$ isn't possible unless the condition $x = y$ is also met.

This is easy to show since we can write $x^2y^2+x^2+xy+y^2$ as $(xy)^2 + \dfrac{3}{4}(x+y)^2 + \dfrac{1}{4}(x-y)^2$, which can only be $0$ if $xy = x+y = x-y = 0$, i.e. $x = y = 0$.

Comment: I don't follow how you converted $x^2+xy+y^2$ as $\frac{3}{4}(x+y)^2+\frac{1}{4}(x-y)^2$

Comment: This is a somewhat unusual trick. You know that $(x+y)^2 = x^2+2xy+y^2$ and $(x-y)^2 = x^2-2xy+y^2$. Hence, $\frac{3}{4}(x+y)^2+\tfrac{1}{4}(x-y)^2$ $= \frac{3}{4}(x^2+2xy+y^2)+\frac{1}{4}(x^2-2xy+y^2)$ $= x^2+xy+y^2$. There are plenty of other ways to show that $x^2+xy+y^2 \ge 0$ with equality iff $x = y = 0$. I just used the one that was easiest to write out.

Answer (score 3):

You're almost done proving that $f$ is injective.

If $f(x)=f(y)$, then $x$ and $y$ have the same sign, because the denominators are always positive. Hence, $xy\ge0$.

Now,
$
x^2+xy+y^2=-x^2y^2
$
implies
$
x^2+xy+y^2+x^2y^2=0
$.
The LHS is a sum of *positive* terms and so each term must be zero. This means that $x=y=0$.

This proves that $f$ is injective.

(Note that when you deduced $x^2+xy+y^2)=-x^2y^2$ from $(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)=x^2y^2(y-x)$ by canceling $x-y$, you assumed that $x-y\ne0$, that is, that $x\ne y$.)

To see that $f$ is surjective, take $a\in\mathbb R$. Then the equation $f(x)=a$ is a cubic equation in $x$ and so has a real solution.

Comment: This seems very strange to me, claiming that it is injective under the constraint that $x=y=0$. Shouldn't $x=y$ no matter what?

Comment: No.  The objective was to obtain a contradiction from assuming distinct x,y with f(x)=f(y). Note that one of your steps was to divide by x-y,( which is fine).The conclusion is that x=y=0, which is the desired contradiction because of the initial assumption that x is not y.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an explicit inverse.

$$x=\frac{\sqrt[3]{2y}}{\sqrt[3]{1+\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{27}y^2}}+\sqrt[3]{1-\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{27}y^2}}}$$

To find this, start with $y=\frac{x^3}{x^2+1}$, and solve for $x$ using Cardano's cubic solution. I subbed $z=x^{-1}$ to get a cubic that was already missing its quadratic term, which simplified the Cardano method a lot.

Comment: I'm afraid that goes way beyond my understanding at this level... I was warned by my prof that trying to find an inverse may end up being too messy, so you've just proven that for me...

Comment: It's not beyond you :) Cardano's method is only about a tad more complicated than completing the square is for solving a quadratic equation. I'd encourage all high school and college math students to give it a go. Here, you'd solve the cubic in $x$: $x^3-x^2y-y=0$. But indeed it would be too long to outline Cardano's method here.